# Oracle Order by - Function Based

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table that has the following 4 columns with some example data

```
Aisle | Rack | Level | Position
  1        1       1         1
  1        2       1         2
  2        1       1         1
  2        2       1         1
  2        3       1         1
  3        1       1         1
  3        2       1         1
```

I wish to write a single query that can Sort records using the following

- First by Aisle (Ascending)
- Then by Rack (Ascending for one Aisle and
  Descending for the next and so on. . . **This is the part that I can't
  seem to figure out if it can be achieved in Oracle**)
- Then by Level (Ascending)
- Then by Position (Ascending)

So the resulting ordered rows will be as follows

```
 Aisle | Rack | Level | Position
  1        1       1         1
  1        2       1         2
  2        3       1         1
  2        2       1         1
  2        1       1         1
  3        1       1         1
  3        2       1         1
```

Is this achievable in Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is enumerate the aisles, so you can identify the odd and even ones.  The function `dense_rank()` does this -- and it is allowed in the `order by` clause.

So:

```
order by aisle,
         (case when mod(dense_rank() over (order by aisle), 2) = 1
               then rack else - rack
          end),
         level, position
```

Actually, if `aisle` has no gaps, you could also use:

```
order by aisle,
         (case when mod(aisle, 2) = 1
               then rack else - rack
          end),
         level, position
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. Just one caveat. It is also possible that I will get only odd (or even) numbered aisles to work on. So alternate aisles should follow Ascending and Descending on Rack. Could that be achieved?

Comment: Ok. Just studied dense_rank and the answer fits :-) Thanks a lot Gordon.

Comment: I am getting an error "ORA-01722: invalid number" when I execute the query. The columns are all VARCHAR2 type. What could I do to make it work? Please help.

Comment: @Guddu . . . The only place where you could get a conversion problem is with `mod(aisle, 2)`.  Instead, you could use `substr(aisle, -1, 1) in ('1', '3', '5', '7', '9')`.